# Sum values with comma in different columns

Tags: awk

My input file is something like:

```
x;y;z
1;1,2;1
0;0,5;1
0;0,75;2
4;1,5;2
2;3,55;1
```

my `awk` is: `'{if($1>0){print $1";"$2-$3";"}'`

my expected output:

```
1;0,2;
4;-0,5;
2;2,55;
```

But my output file doesn't show numbers with comma...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your locale is getting in the way. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Locale-influences-conversions.html

For GNU awk, you need to set the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable, and your LS_NUMERIC environment variable to a locale that uses comma as the decimal separator:

```
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 LC_ALL=en_DK.utf-8 gawk -F';' '$1+0 > 0 {print $1 FS $2-$3 FS}' file
```

```
1;0,2;
4;-0,5;
2;2,55;
```

I use `$1+0 > 0` to avoid printing the header as well. You could also use `NR > 1 && $1 > 0`

---

You can also use `gawk --posix` or `gawk --use-lc-numeric` instead of the POSIXLY_CORRECT env var.

Comment: by the way, it's not working to me. is that need I should have something installed?

Comment: What is your gawk version?

Comment: I'm getting this error `bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_DK.UTF-8): No such file or directory` when setting `LC_ALL=en_DK.UTF-8`. so the problem is clear now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do:

```
awk -F';' '{ gsub(/,/,".", $0); save=$2-$3; gsub(/\./,",", save) }
           NR>1 && $1{print $1, save, ""}' OFS=';' infile
1;0,2;
4;-0,5;
2;2,55;
```

- `NR>1` is skipping the first line.
- `$1` shortened of `$1 >0` is used there.
- `OFS=';'` sets the **O**utput **F**ield **S**eperator to `;`